# AUTOSAR Service software component type

Tags: simulink, autosar

I'm really confused about the AUTOSAR Service software component type.
It is possible to create Atomic software component like application SWC using AUTOSAR Blockset tool, but what about Service software component?

In the AUTOSAR software template documentation it is mentioned that Service software component is configured on the ECU configuration phase.

My question is:
What kind of tools are used in ECU configuration phase?

Comment: It is very hard to provide an answer without any information about your existing knowledge of the AUTOSAR approach. Assuming that you want an answer composed from first principles, it would easily be possible to write several pages worth of text that still only superficially explain how `ServiceSwComponentType` fits into the overall AUTOSAR architecture. My advice would be to attend a training in which the big picture of the configuration of an AUTOSAR ECU is explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Simulink AUTOSAR Blockset allows you to develop ApplicationSwComponents and related higher level parts of SensorActuator-, EcuHwAbstraction-SwComponents and ComplexDrivers. These are mostly above the RTE, or abstracted from the actual HW and this correlates mostly to developing on the level of the "Virtual Function Bus".

The SW components are then later mapped to ECUs (SwcToEcuMapping) and are finally integrated into an ECU SW, including MCAL, HwAbstraction and Service components, which are actually configured with Tools like EB Tresos Studio, ETAS ISOLAR-A/B and Vector Davinci Configurator according to SystemDescription/SystemExtract/EcuExtract and the SW-Component-Descriptions.

Therefore, in Simulink AUTOSAR Blockset, there is no need to actually develop an ServiceComponent, since they are actually part of the AUTOSAR BSW below the RTE (e.g. BswM, StbM, Dem, Dcm, Com, LdCom).